# What is wrong with my encoding, when reading characters from PDF?

Tags: c#, pdf

I'm reading a PDF file with C#, but the characters are coming from another encoding, and returning different characters than those which I expected from when I view the file in a PDF viewer.

I thought a UTF-8 encoding would be correct.

What am I doing wrong?

```
string file = @"c:\document.pdf";
Stream stream = File.Open(file, FileMode.Open);
BinaryReader binaryReady = new BinaryReader(stream);
byte[] buffer = binaryReady.ReadBytes(Convert.ToInt32(stream.Length));
var encoder = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetString(buffer);
```

Comment: PDF is not a simple text file, you can't expect to get the text of the PDF just like that.

Comment: Almost upvoted for making me laugh. I don't think it's worth closing this question, though -- the misunderstanding is almost hilarious but it's now our opportunity to helpfully fix it: mcmonkey4eva has done that perfectly.

Comment: Upvoted - whilst the OP has the wrong end of the stick i'm sure it's an issue other people may come across.

Answer (score 4):

PDF is a very complex multi-part file, it is not just UTF8 text.

If you want to read a PDF file, you must read over the full [PDF File Format Documentation](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference.html) and fully implement the large and complex details of how the file format works.

Comment: You don't have to fully implement it. If you are only interested in extracting the text, you don't need to implement video support, for example.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes: Spoilsport.